# Regex (Notepad++) to search and replace content

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'm not too familiar with the Notepad++ regex option for search and replace, and in need for a little help.

Parsing from one sql syntax to another, I would like to do the following. For all lines with the "pattern" `ADD FOREIGN KEY "**********" ("**")`, I would like to insert som text at section 3 (where the whitespace is)

From

```
   (      1       )(          2         )(3)(4)
   ADD FOREIGN KEY "FK_MY_ACCOUNT_PROJECT" ("id")
```

to

```
   ADD FOREIGN KEY "FK_MY_ACCOUNT_PROJECT" [new text] ("id")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this find and replace in regex mode:

**Find:**

```
(ADD FOREIGN KEY "[^"]+" )(\("[^"]+"\))
```

**Replace:**

```
$1[new text] $2
```

Here is a demo showing that the two groups in fact are getting matched correctly.

### Demo

Comment: Thanks!! You just saved me a lot of time!

Comment: @Kman Feel free to mark this answer correct, casually, if it solved your problem.

Comment: This isn't correct; Notepad++ uses `\n` notation, not `$n` notation.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I initially changed my answer to your comment, but I do recall that Notepad++ actually supports both syntax.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh. Ok then; carry on. :-)

Comment: @wizzwizz4: `\n` notation for replacement are very old.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for... Regular Expressions! Na na na na na n--

Oh, wait... You already knew that... :-/

Anyway... In the "replace" box you can use `\6` to refer to a numbered group, so if you have a regex like this:

```
(ADD FOREIGN KEY) "([^\\]*)" \("([^\\]*)"\)
```

you can replace with this:

```
\1 "\2" insertion ("\3")
```

Comment: hehe..love your intro. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using a character class that means "non backslash"?

Comment: @Toto So it breaks if it encounters an escaped string, because it doesn't handle those properly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I honestly don't know what you're on about! Mind if we take this to chat?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh... That's not how we're meant to deal with that. I have upvoted your answer because it's good; is that satisfactory? (I thought you were confessing to being the one who was serially downvoting me.)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Heh... Now I seem quite the fool for escalating to the CMs. I probably wasn't serially downvoted; my answer quality has not been high of late. Is there any way to attach something to a ticket that hasn't yet been dealt with?